# Ubuntu - PySide module not found for python2 but works fine for python3

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyside

I had PyQt4 running fine with python2 on Ubuntu 12.04.  I then installed python-PySide.  But the installation test would give me a module not found error.  Then I installed python3-PySide and it works fine.  So obviously something to do with my environment paths, but I'm not sure what I need to do.  I'm guessing PySide is automatically checking if python3 exists and if it does then it'll use it regardless.  I need PySide to work with python2.7 because of Qt4.8 compatibility issues.  Any suggestions?

some info about my system:

which python

> > /usr/bin/local/python

which python3

> > /usr/bin/python3

EDIT:

More details about installation test.
After installation, I bring up the python console and try import PySide, as follows:

python

> > > import PySide

ImportError: No module name PySide

But it works fine for python3:

python3

> > > import PySide
> > >
> > > PySide.**version**

'1.1.2'

Comment: What do you mean "the installation test would give me a module not found error". What exactly did you do to install python-PySide, and what exactly happened when you did it?

Comment: Anyway, it's definitely not true that "PySide is automatically checking if python3 exists and if it does then it'll use it regardless." I've got PySide installed on at least 6 linux and Mac boxes for Python 2.6 or 2.7 despite 3.2/3.3/3.4 also existing on all of them. If you're installing with `pip` or `easy_install` or `python setup.py`, you obviously have to use the `pip`/`easy_install`/`python` for Python 2.7, not for 3.3. If you install a binary distro package, you have to install the 2.7 package. And so on. Without knowing what you actually did, I can't tell what you did wrong.

Comment: Also, what packages did `python` and `python3` come from? Is there also a `/usr/bin/python` which is a _different_ 2.7 from `/usr/local/bin/python`? If so, that's probably your problem: you built it for one 2.7 (e.g., the one that came with the distro), and then tried to install it for the other (e.g., one you built manually).

Comment: I edited the question.  I'm looking into this suggestion about difference between python and python2.7.  I'll get back with you if I find anything.  Thanks.

Comment: Hold on, it's not about the difference between python and python2.7, it's about you having two things that are _both_ called `python` (and possibly _also_ both called `python2.7`), e.g., in `/usr` and `/usr/local`.

Comment: I see PySide is in the /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages directories.  And I'm pretty certain that /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages is not the directory being checked by the python interpreter in /usr/bin/local/python.  But how to get that changed?  ...or perhaps a work around?

Comment: I uninstalled pyside and python and reinstalled and I'm still having the same problem.  And if it matters, PyQt4 module is imported without issues using python2.7 interpreter.

Comment: You do not want to make the /usr/local Python 2.7 look at the site-packages for the /usr Python 2.7. That's a recipe for major disaster. They have separate packages for a reason. And if you don't _want_ them to have separate packages, why do you have two separate Python 2.7s in the first place?

Comment: @Mercury. Temporarily rename/move `/usr/local/bin/python`, then re-start `python` and try importing PySide. If that works, it will confirm that you need to remove the python installation under `/usr/local`.

Comment: @ekhumoro: You don't need to temporarily rename/move anything; just run `/usr/bin/python` instead of `python`.

Comment: @abarnert. I wasn't disagreeing with any of the advice you gave. It looks like the installation under `/usr/local` should really be removed, which was what I was trying to focus on. Anyway, you seem to have covered all that in your answer now, so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two independent Python 2.7 installations, one in /usr and one in /usr/local. (And that's on top of the Python 3.x installation you also have.)

This is bound to cause confusion, especially for novices. And it has caused exactly the kind of consuion it was bound to cause.

You've installed PySide into the /usr installation, so it ended up in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. If you run /usr/bin/python, that `import PySide` will probably work fine. (If not, see below.)

But the default thing called `python` and `python2.7` on your PATH is the /usr/local installation, hence `which python` says /usr/local/bin/python, so it can't see PySide at all. So you need to get it installed for the *other* Python as well.

---

Unless you know that you need a second Python 2.7 in /usr/local for some reason, the simplest thing to do would be to scrap it. Don't uninstall it and reinstall it; just uninstall it. You've already got a Python 2.7 in /usr, and you don't need two of them.

---

If you really need to get PySide working with the second 2.7…

Since you still haven't explained how you've been installing PySide despite being asked repeatedly, I can't tell you exactly how to do that. But generally, the key is to make sure to use explicit paths for all Python programs (python itself, python-config, pip, easy_install, etc.) that you have to run. For example, if the docs or blog or voices in your head tell you to run easy_install at some step, run /usr/local/bin/easy_install instead. If there is no such program, then you need to install that. The fact that you already have /usr/bin/easy_install doesn't help—in fact, it hurts.

---

If you *can* get rid of the second Python, but that doesn't fix PySide yet, uninstall, rebuild, and reinstall PySide. Or, even simpler… PySide has pre-made, working binary Ubuntu packages for all of the major Python versions that have Ubuntu packages. Just install it that way.